# How to enable text chat/text box in CSGO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

A while ago, I learned a console command which hides the portion of your HUD which displays what you, your team mates, and your opponents type, as well as the text announcements for "flashbang" or "grenade out." This was very nice for a time since my opponents kept trying to BM me, but now I'm now trying to re-enable it. After quite some time, I haven't been able to find the command to do so. If someone could tell me the console command to unhide my game chat, I would greatly appreciate it!

Also note that I can still press y and u to type, and I hear the click when I send messages and when messages appear. However, I simply can't see any of it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you used `hud_saytext_time 0` to hide your chat. In this case anything higher than 0 will "unhide" it. The number represents the time in seconds the chat will stay visible before it fades away. So a value of 0 displays the chat for 0 seconds, 10 for 10s, etc.

So in your case you can use `hud_saytext_time 12` to display the chat again and after 12 seconds the messages fade away again. 12 seconds is the default value, but you can use any other number as well.